# time the app took while running

Tags: android, performance, mobile, time

I want to calculate the time an app took while running in the foreground activity,

for example : 
if I opened my fb application on android, can I know the time I opened it and the time I closed the application at it or no?

I want to know the time of a running app in the front not the background services.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately a little difficult to do in Android. Generally, this is the idea:

- Every activity's onResume() is called once when that activity appears in front of the user.
- Every activity's onPause() is called once when that activity disappears.

What I do in my app is the following:

- Every activity in my application becomes the subclass of some GenericActivity
- That GenericActivity keeps two arrays, `openArray` and `closeArray`
- Every time onResume() is called, `getCurrentTimeMillis` is pushed onto `openArray`
- Every time onPause() is called, `getCurrentTimeMillis` is pushed onto `closeArray`
- Whenever `openArray` and `closeArray` have the same number of elements, that means the app has been closed. Subtract the first element of `openArray` from the last element of `closeArray`. That should give you the number of milliseconds the application was open in front of the user.

Sorry for the longish answer. Let me know if this makes any sense.